# FindObjectsOfType is not counting instantiated Objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

This code only counts objects from the start but not instantiated objects

```
void Update()
    {
        FindClosestEnemy();
    }

    public void FindClosestEnemy()
    {
        float distanceToClosestEnemy = Mathf.Infinity;
        Enemy closestEnemy = null;
        Enemy[] allEnemies = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Enemy>();

        foreach (Enemy currentEnemy in allEnemies)
        {
            float distanceToEnemy = (currentEnemy.transform.position - this.transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
            if (distanceToEnemy < distanceToClosestEnemy)
            {
                distanceToClosestEnemy = distanceToEnemy;
                closestEnemy = currentEnemy;
            }
        }
```

I tried other closest enemy detectors but somehow only this worked so far

Comment: Guessing you did not add the `Enemy` script to your instantiated objects.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem
When I instantiated the object the z position changed so it couldn't detect the object